# single quote error in ajax call even after escaped

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, escaping

So I'm using plain javascript (no jQuery allowed) and I'm having trouble making Ajax call the old way, one of my variables content has single quote in it:

To escape it I'm doing :

```
url = url.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```

I console log the output, the single quote is replaced by `%27` Then I'm calling it:

```
xhr.open("GET", url, false);
```

But I still get a `500 internal server error`

PS: No error when I remove the single quote from the content.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong at the server?

Comment: One thing is clear: this has nothing to do with JS. Is a stuff about your server. Maybe it has bern misconfigured so the URL submitted when the error shows is causing such error to rise. We cant solve this with the info you provide

Comment: i agree with @pointy . You have to check what input is getting the server and what you are submitting. i personally wouldnt ask for that. Thats stuff you must solve yourself. Of course you have to be careful with quotes, but you first have to know these things. Remember that get requests dont use quotes.

Comment: Pointy, Wonderwhy Thx guys, you opened my eyes on the issue, I could've stayed looking for the error in JS.. It was a problem with the a query that uses the values...

Comment: I spent 2 hours on it, trying different escaping techniques and methodes and didn't even think about server part -silly me. It was indeed a problem with my php that generated the 500 error. Thank you guys for the comments, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

When you build the url, use the escape() function to encode the value of the variable you are inserting.

eg. instead of

```
var url = "http://host.dom.com/path/file.php?var=" + myVar
```

use:

```
var url = "http://host.dom.com/path/file.php?var=" + escape(myVar)
```

Answer (score 1):

`\` is not how you escape URL characters.

Personally, I would advise against `GET` for AJAX requests, unless you're getting static or template-based content (even then...)

You would be much better off using POST, and you can POST any string you like without worrying about encoding.

However, if you want to use GET, or POST with a urlencoded format (so that PHP's `$_POST` will work, for example), then you need to encode correctly, which is done with `escape()`

Comment: This question doesnt make any sense. You are recommending this user to use POST instead of GET _by definition_. This shouldnt be done. Each HTTP verb is destinated to different stuff. The user has to choose which verb to use depending on the action he wants to perform

Comment: And you are supposing the users server is using PHP, while maybe he isnt even the one coding the backend.

Comment: @wonderwhy I cited PHP's `$_POST` as an *example*, of why you might want to use `POST` in a urlencoded format. Personally I POST with JSON, but that's my design.

Comment: Ok. I accept your design, but you have to remember that each thing is destinated to different actions